# Tensorflow's fancy optimizers don't work with variable input size after upgrade to v1.2.1

Tags: tensorflow

I'm currently facing issues with the fancy tensorflow optimizers. The cost function is a simple cross entropy with varying input sizes (defined by None). No optimizer works other than GradientDescentOptimizer. Below are the errors I get:

Momentum Optimizer: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'is_fully_defined'`

RMSPropOptimizer: `ValueError: Shape of a new variable (expanding/step4/deconv/bias/RMSProp/) must be fully defined, but instead was <unknown>.`

AdamOptimizer: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'is_fully_defined'`

GradientDescentOptimizer: Works!

I worked with AdamOptimizer (with the same code) on TF1.0, which broke after an upgrade to TF1.2.1. I then replaced it with MomentumOptimizer, which initially worked (for a few runs), and then it never worked (weird, I know!).

Comment: Sorry you're hitting problems! Do you have a small self-contained code snippet that we can use to reproduce this problem? That would help us track down what's going wrong.

Comment: @PeteWarden, This got resolved. Please see [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11810) tensorflow issue:

Answer (score 0):

the problem is confusing me too, please tell me why this problem happen if you solve it ,thanks a lot
i use the adam optimizer ,and i got the error :
AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'is_fully_defined'

Comment: Please check the conversation [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11810).